# brownian motion scaling

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I have the following probability : 
$P( W(t) > 0 \mbox{ and }W(2t) > 0)$

on some textbook it is claimed that this is equal to 
$P( W(1) > 0 \mbox{ and }W(2) > 0)$
due to the scaling property of the Brownian motion.

As far as I know, the scaling property says that for a real value $c$,
$c*W(t/c²)$ is a Brownian motion.
In that case it seems that it'd work with $c = \sqrt t$, but this would imply that $\sqrt(t)*W_1$ is a Brownian motion , which is wrong.

In short : what is the detailed reason why these 2 probabilities are equal ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the process $(W(t))_{t\ge 0}$ has the same distribution than $(cW(\frac t{c^2}))_{t\ge 0}$, you get with $c = \sqrt t$:
$$
P( W(t) > 0  ;\ \ W(2t) > 0) = 
P\left( cW(\frac t{c^2}) > 0 ;\ \  cW\left(2 \frac t{c^2}\right) > 0\right)\\ =
P\left( W\left(\frac t{c^2}\right) > 0 ;\ \ W\left(2 \frac t{c^2}\right) > 0\right)=
P( W(1) > 0 ; W(2 )> 0)
$$the second equality because $c>0$, and the third because $\frac t{c^2}=1$.

Comment: Maybe one should say that $t$ is fixed here, so $c=\sqrt{t}$ is a valid choice for a constant.

Comment: @MielSharf : this is indeed the point of my question. I understand the formula given in the answer (I briefly alluded to in the question), what I don't really get is why I can consider t fixed, because I'm still considering the whole process (at least 2 values taken  by it, and not only one value)

Comment: The question asks you to compute the probability for $t$ fixed - if it wasn't the case and you needed to do so when $t>0$ varies, then the demand $W(2t)>0$ was already made.